# Strange icon problem in lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, icons

In almost every application (the file browser, the system profiler, even firefox start page) icons don't display properly. Some of them are white squares, and appear if I move my cursor, some of them disappear when I move them. I had this problem with prior versions of Lubuntu as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In system information it says:

```
OpenGL
Vendor : unknown
Renderer : unknown
Version : unknown
Direct rendering : unknown
```

Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot *(you can use https://imgur.com or similar if you don't have enough rep)*, and have you tried changing the icon theme (look for 'Customize look and feel')

Comment: i changed my icon theme but the problem was not solved

Comment: What do you mean about "system profile html file"? If they are NOT private information for you, you can post them on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and reply the link.

Comment: System profiler generates an html file with my hardware info, and I don't know a way to upload it. Also, i found a legacy driver package that supports my graphics card from nvidia. It requires installation without 'X'. How do i close 'X'?

Comment: Should i install this driver first?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by disabling **edge smoothing** in the **Appearance** options, using LXAppearance 0.5.5 (**Start → Preferences → Appearance**). Simple, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Go to **Start → Preferences → Appearance → Font** and uncheck **Disable antialiasing**.